# Magento PWA Studio animated GIF image rendering issue

Tags: magento2, pwa, pwa-studio, help-wanted, pwa-theme

I want to use an animated GIF image in my Magento PWA Studio project, but when the image is rendering in the browser a suffix code is being added to it like this

The image has been added by the page-builder and is being directly fetched as content and all images are by default optimized.
https://pwa.local.com:2000/media/wysiwyg/gifanimation_image_400x400px_1.gif?auto=webp&format=pjpg&quality=85

Since this `auto=webp&format=pjpg&quality=85` is getting added at the end so GIF is not animating.

Can we somehow remove this from GIF image? so this is no longer optimized and keeps its animation property intact.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the optimization feature by overriding the

> node_modules/@magento/peregrine/lib/util/makeUrl.js

in your theme/package by specifying it in

> componentOverrideMapping.js

and stop the optimization condition by checking if the incoming file format is gif inside the makeURL.js file

```
if(getFileType === "gif"){
//do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, @Aditya Yadav.